# netstat output: unexpected kind 634 which 0x27

Tags: macos, netstat

When running the `netstat -tuln` command on macOS terminal I get a strange output at the bottom:

```
... truncated...
e85ca8f83c2f500b dgram       0      0                0 e85ca8f83c2f3fa3                0 e85ca8f83c2f4db3
e85ca8f83c2f4f43 dgram       0      0                0 e85ca8f83c2f4e7b e85ca8f83c2f4e7b                0
e85ca8f83c2f4e7b dgram       0      0                0 e85ca8f83c2f4f43 e85ca8f83c2f4f43                0
e85ca8f83c2f4db3 dgram       0      0                0 e85ca8f83c2f3fa3                0 e85ca8f83c2f406b
e85ca8f83c2f406b dgram       0      0                0 e85ca8f83c2f3fa3                0                0
e85ca8f83c2f3fa3 dgram       0      0 e85ca8fd077fd09b                0 e85ca8f83c2e5c8b                0 /private//var/run/syslog
unexpected kind 634 which 0x27a
```

The output finishes with `unexpected kind 634 which 0x27a`.  I was unable to find anything about this in [the manual](https://linux.die.net/man/8/netstat).

I'm not very familiar with the `netstat` command. Any ideas about why this output?

Comment: Wait, you're linking to the manual of the GNU netstat utility, typically found in Linux. You have macOs, which as far as I can tell does not ship GNU utilities. So, which kind of netstat do we deal with?

Comment: Yep, macOS's netstat is unrelated to the man page you linked to. Here's where the "unexpected kind" comes from: https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/network_cmds/blob/c24bcf20864e90785f6c6e5c60eb3ea9be0eeb9e/netstat.tproj/inet.c#L307

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The source code can be found in the link provided in the comments above.

The unexpected kind message is printed when `netstat` extracts some data from the buffer and upon evaluation it does not match one of a given set of constants that represent network connection states. Those being:

`XSO_SOCKET`, `XSO_RCVBUF`, `XSO_SNDBUF`, `XSO_STATS`, `XSO_INPCB`, `XSO_TCPCB`.

Unfortunately, these constant structures are not defined within Apple's GitHub [network_cmds](https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/network_cmds/tree/c24bcf20864e90785f6c6e5c60eb3ea9be0eeb9e) repository code.

Maybe this is due to some new connection protocol such as `QUIK` which doesn't match the existing profiles and `netstat` has not been updated. Not sure. Presumably other tools such as `Wireshark` could lend some visibility into which connections are not effectively parsed by the the `netstat` output